# Callout delay when HttpRequest is invoked in a trigger account

Tags: apex, callout

I'm doing a http request from salesforce, when I receive the response, I want to update an account field but it is visible until I refresh the page. Everything is in after update. Is there a way to see my info when I save my record?

Comment: Last I checked you can't make callouts from a trigger context. Is there a @future(callout=true) attribute on method somewhere before the callout occurs? This makes the call async. Hence you need to refresh the page to pickup the results of the callout.

Comment: Nice catch @DanielBallinger. I was half-way answering the question with similar response to BobBuzzard's answer :)